# Touchpad does not work under Windows 10, *DOES* work Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers, touchpad

Unlike most people here, my laptops touchpad does not work under **Windows 10**, it *DOES* work under **Win7**. NOT the otherway round

So it's not a hardware problem, and I've checked, the cables are in place.

The laptop is a Lenovo G50-80-80L000h2us, its [manual is here](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g_z_50_series_hmm.pdf)

If it's a driver problem, I have tried to find drivers, but I failed.

Question: ***How do I get the touchpad working under windows 10?***

Comment: Drivers are at Lenovo's website. If it hasn't drivers for Windows 10 then that Windows version isn't supported officially by the manufacturer. You may then try to find drivers from the touchpad's manufacturer.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I can not find out the name of the manufacturer and type of the touch pad, that info seems to be unavailable.

Comment: It should be in device manager, but your first resource, again, is Lenovo.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Found it. I had accidentally switched it off, with the function keys.

Answer (score -1):

You can install the Windows 7 drivers under Windows 10. If they are not signed then you will have to ***“Disable driver signature enforcement.”*** to get them to install.

Try this driver:
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/g50-70-notebook-lenovo/downloads/ds039874